# Get value from HTML page to angularJS file

Tags: angularjs, html

I tried to get the HTML page value to angularJS function , The below steps are which i tried.

HTML page :

```
<label class="item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label cont_det_label">First Name</span>
    <p class="contact_display" id="txtFirstName" ng-model="testName">Satya</p>
  </label>
```

angularJS Page :

```
.controller('SocialNetworkCtrl', ['$scope','$http','$state','ContactsService','$ionicNavBarDelegate','$ionicLoading','$ionicPopup',function($scope, $http, $state, ContactsService, $ionicNavBarDelegate, $ionicLoading,$ionicPopup) {

                                  $scope.showUserProfile = function() {
                                  $state.go("linkedin");

                           var firstname = (document.getElementById("txtFirstName").value);


                                  }
                                  }])
```

### So I need var firstname = Satya ?? Is it correct way please guide me to access this value .

Comment: `ng-model` in `<p>`?

Comment: Study some angular tutorials. The one in documentation site is well worth the time spent

Answer (score 1):

its a text node, you will require `.innerHTML` or '.innerText', `.value` is for form inputs

```
 var firstname = (document.getElementById("txtFirstName").innerHTML);
```

and don't use ng-model on a `p` element, change it to like this

```
<p class="contact_display" id="txtFirstName">{{testName}}</p>
```

just use `$scope.testName` to get the value, no need for `firstname = (document.getElementById("txtFirstName").innerHTML);` querying DOM for value is `jQuery` style, use angular the $scope for 2 way bindings

[Read more at official doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

**Update** here is updated function on `loginCtrl`

```
.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
     $scope.testNameData = 'Satya';
     $scope.doLogin = function() {
        alert($scope.testNameData);
     };
}])
```

If you really want to go jQuery way here is what you can do, its not recommended, you should use `angular directive` to do DOM manipulation

```
$scope.showUserPro = function() {

    $ionicLoading.show();

    // Here i need the value of <p tag>
    var name = document.getElementById("txtFirstName"),
        firstNameFromHtmlPtag = name.innerText;

    console.log(firstNameFromHtmlPtag, 'Doing API Call 1');

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Saqueib , But i tried both .innerHTML and .value but no response received in the var firstname ??

Comment: As per your point i tried but getting "undefined" in the alert for firstname ??

Comment: Sorry i can not create a fiddle r8 now , But i need to know in the HTML page <p class="contact_display" id="txtFirstName">{{testName}}</p> where can i insert the value Satya , I tried after testName but getting Undefined ????

Comment: HI Saqueib , as per your note this way for set the value right , But i need get the <p> value in the JS page.

Comment: you can use `{{testName}}` in <p> tag, it will be binded, if you change the scope `$scope.testNameData` it will always update the <p> tag, can you tell whats you want to build

Comment: Yup Saqueib , I have screen called cantact details HTML page in that i have a value <p tag> for FirstName and eMail , in these fields what are the values found the <p tag FirstName and eMail> , I need to get the <p tag> value in the controller.js page variable because i've a web service call in that call i need to set this firstName and eMail value as the parameter thats it.

Comment: if you can paste your all code in pastebin and share the link will be easy

Comment: Hi Saqueib please find the pastebin link below ...1) HTML http://pastebin.com/NPaXhkjQ  2) JS http://pastebin.com/YqdT1u1B

Comment: HTML:                                                                                                            <p class="contact_display" id="htmlData" >SuthanM</p>
NG_JS:                                                                                                          $scope.showUserPro = function() {                                                            var htmlDataValue = document.getElementById("htmlData");
var htmlResult = htmlDataValue.innerText;
console.log(htmlResult, 'Doing Html Value');
alert(htmlResult); }

Comment: HI Saqueib , As per ur note i tried the above steps but it's not throw the answer , might be some issues found 'll check and confirm you.

Comment: HI Saqueib , Thanks for your support I'm using rootScope for assign the global variable in the JS file itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
var firstName = $scope.testName

<input ng-model="testName" />
```

**testName is the ng-model** name that you have give. It will be automatically binded to your controller. **No need** the get the value using document.getElementById

Wrong usage , why ng-model in `<p>` tag??

**Update**

Change your fiddle with the following code, it will work. Also make sure framework is selected properly (as in the image) 
[image: FrameWork and Extension]

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="testController">
    <input ng-model="testDataName" ng-change="check()" /> {{testDataName}}
    After ng-change : {{checkName}}
</div>

 function testController($scope) {
    $scope.testDataName="Dummy Name";
    $scope.check = function () {
        $scope.checkName=$scope.testDataName;
        console.log($scope.checkName);
    };
}
```

Comment: HI Jan thanks for your valuable reply but my scenario is different , Because actually what i need is for example my contactDetail Screen I've a paragraph value like Suthan M , So next Screen I need this paragraph value in the variable (eg: var testName = the paragraph value) , Finally i need get the <p> tag value already in html page , that value i need in the JS page is it clear i tried so many ways but not able to get the value.